# How do I replace the 4th "|" in each line with a space

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge list of data in this format.

```
DATA1|DATA2|00/00|JOHN|SMITH|
```

How can I modify this with regex so I can replace the 4th "|" with a space so It will output it like this?

```
DATA1|DATA2|00/00|JOHN SMITH|
```

Thank you very much

Comment: `^(?:[^|]+\|){3}[^|]+(\|)`

Comment: @dawg What do I put in the replace with box?

Comment: I do not know your application. That regex will find the fourth `|` in a line. Up to you from here...

Answer (score 1):

*Find What:*

```
^((?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*)\|
```

*Replace With:*

```
\1
```

Note that you need to add a space after `\1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/1)

**OR**

*Find What:*

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*\K\|
```

*Replace With:*

```
 replace with a space.
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `(([^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+)\|)` with `\2`. Here's what the regex does:

`(` beginning of the first capture group
`(` beginning of the second capture group

**The below portion is repeated three times**
`[^\|]` matches any character that is not the `|` character.
`+` makes sure that the above part (`[^\|]` is matched one or more times)
`\|` matches the `|` character literally
**The above portion is repeated three times**

`[^\|]` matches any character that is not the `|` character.
`+` makes sure that the above part (`[^\|]` is matched one or more times)

`)` end of the second capture group
`\|` matches the `|` character literally
`)` end of the first capture group.

Next, you can replace it with `\2` (with a space at the end). [Here's a live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ6aH3/1). Make sure to use the `g (global)` modifier with your regex (typically at the end of the expression), in order to make sure that it does not return on the first find.